# Delete table record in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Within the while I created the delete button:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   
$tabela2 .= '<tr>';
$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['IdEstado'].'</td>';
$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRequis'].'</td>';
$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Funcionario'].'</td>';
$tabela2 .= '<td><form action="./delete" method="post">'; 
$tabela2 .= '<input type="hidden" name="IdEstado" value="'.$rows_cursos['IdEstado'].'">'; 
$tabela2 .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>'; //aqui está o seu botão
$tabela2 .= '</form></td>'; //só fechando o form
$tabela2 .= '</tr>'; 
    }
$tabela2 .= '</tr>';
$tabela2 .='</tbody>'; 
$tabela2 .= '</table>';
$tabela2 .= '</div>';
echo $tabela2;
```

The `action = "./delete"` I put it this way because I'm working on wordpress and the `action` of this form is equal to `action = "delete.php"`.

After deleting.php I have this code:

```
$id = $_POST['IdEstado'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM `centrodb`.`RequisicaoLuvas` WHERE `RequisicaoLuvas`.`id` = " . $id;
mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($conn);

$sql1 = "DELETE FROM `centrodb`.`EstadoLuvas` WHERE `EstadoLuvas`.`IdEstado` = " . $id;
mysqli_query($conn,$sql1) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($conn);
```

When I click the delete button it does not delete anything in the database table.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Your button is a button and not a type="submit".

Comment: @Prashanth Benny I am not receiving any errors, neither on the page nor in the chrome console

Comment: @Demodave is going to delete.php page

Comment: you could use die(mysqli_error($conn)); to display the exact error

Comment: do you get an id echo $id?

Comment: echo your query string then try that in your db.

Comment: Also; you closed the connection after the first query so the 2nd delete query won't happen.

Comment: This is open to sql injection. Either use a prepared statement or use `(int)` on the POST array if it will always be an integer.

Comment: You're not getting errors because error reporting isn't enabled and you didn't use `mysqli_error($conn)` as previously stated.

Comment: You should bind_parameters in order to avoid sql inyection try with something like this http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: The problem was even type = "button", I switched to type = "submit" and already deleted

Comment: @manelseo I was seeing the link that indicated to me to see, but I could not understand how to avoid SQL injection, can you give an example how to avoid in order to understand?

Comment: @bruno binding the parameters the system will not use the parameter as a part of the query avoiding sql inyection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easy with PDO and avoid SQL Inyection if you want to use mysqli you can do something similar. Follow this link: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST['IdEstado'];
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $dataBaseHost . "; dbname=" . $dataBaseName . "", $dataBaseUserName, $dataBasePassword);
 $prepared_statement = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM RequisicaoLuvas WHERE id=:id");
 $prepared_statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
 $prepared_statement->execute();
 $pdo = null;
 ?>
```